# MVC Web App not communicating with data source

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I just deployed my MVC web app on a windows shared host. I keep getting NullReferenceException errors whenever I do something that requires communication with the database. I noticed that if I bypass using the context class and use an in-method Sql connection (As in SQLConnection, SqlCommand, SQLAdapter) etc it finds the data in the database. But using normal entity framework still gives the errors. Note this ONLY happens in the live site, not when I run in Debug mode in Visual Studio.

Can anyone help? I have a feeling its something to do with my host.

**UPDATE**

This is the error I get when accessing just one of my models.

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP._Page_Views_InvoiceAdmin_Index_cshtml.Execute() in f:\Domains\ROM30\proopt.co.za\proopt.co.za\proopt.co.za\Views\InvoiceAdmin\Index.cshtml:40
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +103
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +62
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +256
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1a.b*_17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass2a.b*_20() +75
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass25.b*_22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9628700
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

The code causing this in my cshtml view is `@foreach (var item in Model)`

My host's trust level is medium, I should add.

**Update 2**

Ok I just attempted to deploy a brand new MVC app from Visual Studio, and that gave me no errors when trying to access models (I made a simple Students model and created a new "Student" in the database, something that would not work in my actual MVC app. Any ideas?

**Update 3**

Here is my DbContext class, which populates my models:

```
namespace ProOptInteractive.Models
{
    public class OnlineEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ServiceCategory> ServiceCategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Callout> Callouts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CalloutDetail> CalloutDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LiabilityRate> LiabilityRates { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Technician> Technicians { get; set; }
        public DbSet<QualificationLevel> QualificationLevels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My connection string is:

Comment: Show us the exception message and the code which causes the exception

Comment: Going to need to see the code in question, too.

Comment: The exception is just showing us that your model is null.  You need to show us the code that populates the model, show us your connection string (make sure to take out any sensitive information like the username and password), etc..  The fact that your model is null is not the bug.

Comment: That is not the code that populates the model, that is just the definition of you dbcontext.  We need to see your CODE..

Comment: I  don't think there's anything wrong with my code as if I run the program in debug mode locally, it pulls the data from the remote database as normal.

Comment: @barnacle.m *We need to see your code*. Please.